# Embedded signing flow returns ttl_expired status

Tags: docusignapi

I have implemented DocuSign's [Embedded signing flow](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning) with our application. Our use case : customer of our app sends email with link to the client that has to sign a document. That is our app link. On clicking on email we are opening DocuSign (in IFrame of our app) and open url as following :

> https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/startinsession.aspx?t=776a1a9c-72c6-4c62-9243-2807db18f78a

If user clicks on link and finish signing/declining everything goes OK. Elsewhere user opens a link, do nothing and re-open a link immediately DocuSign sends ttl_expired status. Same response I get if user clicks on link after some time - let say 1hour.

As I found online, for this flow :

> - Recipient Tokens expire five minutes after they are issued by DocuSign. If a Recipient Token URL is invoked after it is expired, the user is re-directed to the Callback URL specified in the RequestRecipientToken request with event code TTLExpired.
> - Recipient Tokens expire upon being successfully invoked.
> - Active Recipient Tokens expire if the envelope is voided.
>     Developer Guide 85
> - Five minutes is the default "Time to Live" for Recipient tokens. This is a configurable setting.

[Source](https://community.docusign.com/t5/Account-Management/Embedding-Signing-Configurable-TTL-Setting/td-p/797)

If it is like that, which DocuSign flow can meet our use case, or I have to change something in existing flow ?

Comment: You'll have to generate a new envelope each time the user wants to view/sign the document.

Comment: thanks, is it better than to use some other flow for our use case ?

Comment: It's what we're doing for deep links in an email. The link in the email isn't actually the docusign url, it's a link to our api which then pulls the user data we saved and creates the envelope each time the email link is clicked. We expire the email link only after signing is complete.

Comment: that looks like our scenario, we are also sending email with our app link, not DS. And if you are non stop recreating envelopes, do you support multi-signer mode ? And is this scenario suggested by DS ?

Comment: We dont need any multi-signing. But if we did I'd use Connect to capture the first signed event then send out for the second signature. If you're allowing collaboration I could see this being horrible.

Comment: @DaveBriand should post his comments as an answer, they are inline with what I'd suggest as well :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to create a new envelope each time you encounter this error.  In fact, that's a bad decision as that will start to eat up at your monthly envelope limits that are allowed on your DocuSign account plan.

Instead, if you generate a signing URL and the recipient opens it but does not sign and closes out and eventually needs to get back in and sign that envelope, you can simply generate a new recipient view (signing URL).

With the newly generated URL the same rules apply... if they don't use it within 5 minutes or they open but don't sign the once again you'll need to create a new URL token, but that's much better than wasting a whole new envelope.  That simply counts as one extra API call, which you are allowed 1,000 per hour per account.

Answer (score 1):

The retrieved URL is one-time use and expires after 5 minutes.  Once Docusign detects that you have loaded a retrieved URL, it will no longer work.  As stated in a previous answer, if you haven't loaded it within 5 minutes, it will also no longer work.  The ttl_expired code will appear in both cases.

You just have to request the signing URL again if its used or expired.  Do **not** recreate the envelope.